# Having trouble with calculations... what's wrong?

Tags: java, actionlistener

Having trouble calculating this out. The rest of the coding is fine but this one class. The error focuses on one line.

- retail_price = double.parseDouble(input1) * (double.parseDouble(input2) / 100);

The errors tell me that "class expected" "; expected" and "not a statement". Where am I going wrong because this seems correct to me?

```
private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

    // The actionPerformed method executes when the user clicks the calculate button
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        double retail_price;
        String input1;
        String input2;

        //Get the number from the users input in priceFeild1
        input1 = priceField1.getText();

        //Get the number from the users input in priceFeild2
        input2 = priceField2.getText();

        // Calculate out the operation below to find the retail_price
        retail_price = double.parseDouble(input1) * (double.parseDouble(input2) / 100);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The retail price of the item is: $" + retail_price );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The name of the class containing `parseDouble` is [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html), not `double`. They are *not* synonyms. `double` is the name of the primitive type, and primitives do not have methods.

So you need:

```
retail_price = Double.parseDouble(input1) * (Double.parseDouble(input2) / 100);
```

However, you should also *strongly* consider using `BigDecimal` instead of `Double` anyway, as that's a better match for currency values.

Additionally, I'd recommend:

- Following Java naming conventions, using `camelCase` instead of underscore separators
- Giving your variables more meaningful names - what are `input1` and `input2` meant to represent? A price and a discount, perhaps?
- Declaring variables only where you need to, rather than at the start of the method
- Considering what you want to happen if the value entered by the user isn't a valid number
- Considering whether you care about internationalization (e.g. a user entering "10,50" instead of "10.50". If so, look at `NumberFormat` and `DecimalFormat`

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I have made all the necessary changes regarding my variables. If I were trying to figure out how to prevent the user to enter an invalid number, how would you do it?

Comment: What would be the most efficient way is what I'm asking?

Comment: @user2981423: There are various aspects to that - you might want to prevent any letter characters from being typed, for example, but you should also catch the exception which is thrown when trying to parse invalid text. Efficiency (in terms of execution-time performance) is almost certainly irrelevant - just how often quickly do you think a user can enter invalid data, and does it really matter if they have a very slight (almost certainly imperceptible) pause after each attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Double.parseDouble(input1)
```

Answer (score 1):

parsing of double `retail_price = Double.parseDouble(input1) * (Double.parseDouble(input2) / 100);`